# How to assign a role to an application without using the Role manager?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, function-call

> Good afternoon , I am facing a problem . My phone does not support
> android 10 . But I only found the solution through the RoleManager.
> Below I describe what I did.
> How can I assign a role to an application without using the RoleManager?

> **main class**

```
private fun requestScreeningRole() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val roleManager = requireContext().getSystemService(ROLE_SERVICE) as RoleManager
        val isHeld = roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING)
        if (!isHeld) {
            val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 123)
        }
        } else {

        }
    }
```

> ```
> **manifest**
> ```

```
 <service android:name=".Service.ScreeningService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

service

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class ScreeningService : CallScreeningService() {

```
var blacklistednumber = arrayListOf<User>()
var blacklistednumberBase = arrayListOf<Base>()


override fun onScreenCall(details: Call.Details) {
    val repositorys = UserRepository(UserDatabase.getDatabase(this).userDao())
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        blacklistednumber.clear()
        blacklistednumberBase.clear()
        blacklistednumber.addAll(repositorys.readAllDataNoLiveData())
        blacklistednumberBase.addAll(repositorys.readAllDataBaseNoLiveData())
        val phoneNumber = details.handle.schemeSpecificPart
        blacklistednumber.forEach {
            if ("+${it.phone}" == phoneNumber.toString()) {
                disconnectCall(details, phoneNumber)

            } else {
                blacklistednumberBase.forEach {
                    if ("+${it.phone}" == phoneNumber.toString()) {
                        disconnectCall(details, phoneNumber)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private fun disconnectCall(details: Call.Details, phoneNumber: String) {
    respondToCall(details, buildResponse())
}

private fun buildResponse(): CallResponse {
    return CallResponse.Builder()
        .setRejectCall(true)
        .setDisallowCall(true)
        .setSkipNotification(true)
        .setSkipCallLog(true)
        .build()
}
```

}